# @Size annotation doesn't seem to work for my class

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, annotations

I have a Spring Boot Controller with an endpoint that accepts the following Configuration class (as json). The class has the param `maxIterations` and has a `@Size` annotation set to `9000`.

```
...
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Configuration {
    // Max iterations
    @Size(max = 9000)
    private Integer maxIterations;

    ...
}
```

The problem is that when making the `POST` call to that endpoint with the following `json` it does not return an error or warning stating the the `maxIterations` parameter is higher than `9000`.

```
{
  "maxIterations": 15000
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@PostMapping()
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String doSomething(@RequestBody Configuration configuration) {
    ...
}
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: The `@Size` annotation is just an annotation. If you use a valdiator that makes use of these kind of annotations, then the annotation has an effect; otherwise nothing happens. Are you using a validator? If so, show the code. If not, that's the reason nothing happens.

Comment: Even if validation works, it does not what you think. The [`@Size` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) is for constraining the size of character sequences and collections. For constraining numbers, you should use `@Min` and `@Max`.

Comment: Initially it was `@Max`, that didn't work as well.

Comment: You should add `@Valid` or `@Validated` to your `@RequestBody` annotated method argument. If you don't then validation will not be triggered.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, you should be using `@Max(9000)` as `@Size` should only be used for arrays, Strings, collections and maps.

```java
public class Configuration {
    @Max(9000)
    private Integer maxIterations;

    // ...
}
```

Additionally, you should use the `@Valid` annotation within your controller so that the bean validator knows that there are constraints within the `Configuration` class, for example:

```java
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String doSomething(@Valid @RequestBody Configuration configuration) {
    // ...
}
```

This only works if you have a proper implementation of the **Java Validation API** on your classpath. This can be done by adding the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Before Spring boot 2.3, this was automatically included within the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, but now you have to manually include the dependency.

Comment: It still doesn't return an error with these.
Tried with both `@Valid` and `@Validated`.

Comment: @VaheKarapetyan I actually tested this myself, this should work, the code I used can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/g00glen00b/23c66572021542c6b16b5dbabe16ad1c), in addition of the request and the error I get. What request body are you sending?

Comment: @VaheKarapetyan Additionally, provide a list of dependencies you use. The validation processor bean is only created if a proper implementation of the validation API is on the classpath. By default, if you use **spring-boot-starter-web**, you should have the **hibernate-validator** on your classpath.

Comment: In this case I had to add the following starter to provide validators configuration: <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>

Answer (score 0):

Below dependency works for me:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Earlier i was using below dependency which causing some unkown issues for validations

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```